# Quantum Linear Algebra

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, unitarity, matrix-representation

Find a 4 x 4 unitary matrix U such that U = eiA. (Possibly up to multiplying by a unit scalar, U is a matrix seen in the course.) Verify your calculation by showing how if U were given, one can obtain A.
Where Define |µ> = 1/2[1, −1, −1, 1]T and A = π |µ> <µ|.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the definition of taking the matrix exponential $e^M$: find the spectral decomposition of $M=\sum_m\lambda_mP_m$ where $P_m$ are projectors satisfying $\sum_mP_m=I$. Then
$$
e^M=\sum_me^{\lambda_m}P_m.
$$

In this case, you have $P_0=A/\pi$, $\lambda_0=i\pi$, $P_1=I-P_0$ and $\lambda_1=0$. Thus,
$$
e^{iA}=e^{i\pi}|\mu\rangle\langle\mu|+(I-|\mu\rangle\langle\mu|)=I-2|\mu\rangle\langle\mu|.
$$